# I am trying to make NPC that is randomly walking and attacks players

Tags: roblox

I am trying to make NPC that is randomly walking and attacks players. Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

A good starting place for NPCs that walk around and attack players are zombies. I would recommend looking at the [R15 Zombie with #### sounds](https://www.roblox.com/library/899961051/R15-Zombie-with-sounds) model in the Toolbox. Once you drag it into the Workspace, there is a script in there called Script that is fairly straightforward in how it moves the zombie around to attack other humanoid characters.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that is complex in itself, but if you are new to scripting, it might be best to just get the free-modeled zombie in the toolbox, and then change it's appearance through the explorer window. If you want to go the long route, it might be better to learn how to use the function :MoveTo. The Roblox Developer website provides good info on how to use these things. As for attacking people, just put a script in the arm that damages on touch. Here's something that might work, (put it in the same model as the humanoid):

```
local larm = script.Parent:FindFirstChild("Left Arm")
local rarm = script.Parent:FindFirstChild("Right Arm")

function findNearestTorso(pos)
    local list = game.Players:GetPlayers()
    local torso = nil
    local dist = 10
    local temp = nil
    local human = nil
    local temp2 = nil
    for x = 1, #list do
        temp2 = list[x]
        if temp2.Character:IsA("Model") then
            temp = temp2.Character:FindFirstChild("Torso")
            human = temp2.Character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
            if (temp ~= nil) and (human ~= nil) and (human.Health > 0) then
                if (temp.Position - pos).magnitude < dist then
                    torso = temp
                    dist = (temp.Position - pos).magnitude
                end
            end
        end
    end
    return torso
end

while true do
    wait(0.1)
    local target = findNearestTorso(script.Parent.Torso.Position)
    if target ~= nil then
        script.Parent.Humanoid:MoveTo(target.Position, target)
    end
end
```

For the damage script, you can use this if you add it to one of the arms:

```
script.Parent.Touched:connect(function(part)
    if part.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
        part.Parent.Humanoid:TakeDamage(30)
    end
end)
```